# Redondear esquinas al hacer click

Tags: css

Tengo el siguiente boton:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como les muestro así se ve cuando se le da click.

redondee el boton con `border-radius` mi pregunta es:

¿Se puede redondear también esas esquinas al hacer click?

Comment: Esa línea externa se llama "outline" y no se puede redondear, la agrega el navegador. Simplemente agrega la regla `outline: none;` para desaparecerla.

Comment: Gracias la idea era que no se viera, acertaste

Comment: Por motivos de accesibilidad, si quitas el `outline`, al menos plantéate poner un `box-shadow` que lo simule (y que sí se redondeará correctamente).

Answer (score 0):

No, no se puede, pero como te recomiendan debes eliminar el outline, pero simularlo con otro box-shadow, algo así:

```css
button{
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3em;
 padding: .5em 2em;
 border: cyan solid 1px;
}

button:focus{
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px blue ;
}
```

```html
<button> SOMETHING </button>
```